# Find List of Players That use Same IP in MySql DataBase in Java

Tags: java, sql, search

I log connections from players on my server in a Mysql DB, There is a table named IPDataBase. I would like to check if a User uses multiple accounts with the same IP.

The Table Looks More or less like so:

```
PlayerName       |    IP

Player1          |    0.0.0.0

Player2          |    0.0.0.1

Player1          |    0.0.0.2
```

Using non real examples of course. With that i want to say that the same player name can be in there but with a different IP. So as soon as a player connects it checks if the same player has logged in with the same ip already, if this is not the case it will insert a new Line.

I now have a boolean method that should return whether or not there is a player with the same ip. My code up to now is:

note: since its for a Bukkit plugin the type Player is a Player and the String Playername is obtained by player.getName()

```
public boolean checksameip(Player player, String IP){
    boolean ret = false;
    String playername = player.getName();
    try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WebCom", "root", "MyPW");

        Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT PlayerName FROM IPDataBase WHERE IP='"+IP+"'");

        if(rs.next()){
        //there are results

            //have no clue what to put here :S

        }else{

            ret = false;
        }

        con.close();

    }catch(Exception e){

        logm("Could Not Send Data To MYSQL DATABASE SERVER");
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Note that for multiple users behind the same router, the IP-number will be the same.

Comment: I know, but its really not important. because i won't stop them from connecting, i will only log it.

Comment: Echoing @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, consider a typical "gaming party" where you have a bunch of people playing your game behind the same NAT router... ALL of them will appear to you to be using a single IP.  Of what value is it to you to log this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you want to get all the players who share the same IP? Do it like this:

```
public String[] getPlayersWithIP(String ip) {
    try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WebCom", "root", "MyPW");
        Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT PlayerName FROM IPDataBase WHERE IP='"+ip+"'");
        HashSet<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
        int i=0;
        while(rs.next()){
            result.add(getString("PlayerName"));
        }
        con.close();
        return result.toArray(new String[0]);
    }catch(Exception e){
        logm("Could Not Send Data To MYSQL DATABASE SERVER");
        return new String[0];
    }
}
```

Returns a `String` array containing all the different playernames who's player have the IP `ip`. If no player with that IP is in the DB or an exception is thrown an empty array is returned. If the returned array's size is greater than 1, two or more people with the same IP logged in on your server.

Answer (score 0):

What about comparing the name of player returned by the DB with the name of player passed in method. If there are users other than the one passed to method, than mutiple a/c's have been used with same IP.

Comment: that would work yes, but i want to find out all the people behind the same ip, there might be more than two... How do i create a loop that would return every player that used the same ip.